# Qt.inputMethod doesn't exist? Qt 5.3.1

Tags: qt, qml, android-input-method

I want to access these `Properties` mentioned here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html

- **application** : object
- **inputMethod** : object
- **platform** : object

But I can't find them, the compiler complains about it, I used:

```
import QtQml 2.2
```

but nothing changed!

What to do?

---

**Edit:**
Here's the code in which I'm trying to use `Qt.inputMethod`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: parentWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Main Window")

    TextInput
    {
        id: text_input1
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.pixelSize: parent.height-4
        text: qsTr("TEXT")
        Keys.onReturnPressed:
        {
            focus = true;
            Qt.inputMethod.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(Qt.inputMethod.hide);` returns: `qml: function() { [code] }`, therefore there.